# Entity Framework 5: Creating Collections Using Code First

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I'm new to the code first paradigm, so please bear with me.  I can't get a collection/list/array of primitives or custom classes created on my database from my entity class.  So, as a result, I can't seed the table properly.  No error, just get an entity table that has every property except my collection.  I'm using EF5, VS2010, MVC4, and SqlExpress.  What am I doing wrong?

**My Entity Class:**

```
public class MyEntity
{    
    public int MyEntityID { get; set; } // GOOD
    public string Property1 { get; set; }  // GOOD
    public bool Property2 { get; set; }  // GOOD
    public IList<CustomClass> CustomClassList { get; set; }  //BAD, NOT CREATED ON DB
    public CustomClass[] CustomClassArray { get; set; }  //BAD, NOT CREATED ON DB
}
```

**My Custom Class:**

```
[ComplexType]
public class CustomClass
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

**My Configuration/Migration Class**

```
public class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
    {
        context.MyEntity.AddOrUpdate(x => x.MyEntityID,
             new MyEntity()
             {
                 Property1 = "abc",
                 Property2 = "xyz",
                 CustomClassList = new List<CustomClass> {new CustomClass{Title="Help"}}
             }
        context.SaveChanges();       
    }
}
```

**My Global.asax.cs Application_Start() Method**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
    SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, Configuration>());
}
```

When I try to create a new database, I get the same result:

```
<!--NO LUCK-->
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS2;Initial Catalog=TESTDB_2;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />   
<!--NO LUCK-->
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS2;Initial Catalog=TESTDB_3;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: I can't help with migration but collections should be declared as `ICollection<>` e.g. `public ICollection<CustomClass> CustomClassList { get; set; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framwork does not support collections of primitive or complex types. If you want a collection it has to be a collection of entities (i.e. they need to have key properties). If you have a collection of entities it - in the simplest case - will be modeled as a separate table and appropriate foreign keys will be created as needed (depending on the cardinality of the relation).
In your case CustomClass is ignored since it is not an entity and is used in a collection (which is also ignored since it is not a collection of entity types). CustomClassArray is ignored since arrays are not supported at all as you cannot add/remove an item without re-allocating the array.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I've looked at Julie Lerman's article and she has a collection of ComplexTypes - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding her?

Comment: These are entities and not complex types. See here for more details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee382831.aspx. Complex type is a collection of (primitive or complex) properties (the canonical example is Address complex type) - you can create properties of complex types on your entities to group properties but they will be modeled as columns in your table (think: flattened). They cannot have key properties and you cannot have a collection of complex types (otherwise how would you model this in the database given that this is only a means to group properties?).

Comment: Good explanation.  So why doesn't my example work in the world of complex types?  It looks like it should.  I added a key to my example and it creates another table, but no field (foriegn key?) in the MyEntity table.  Also, the new table isn't seeded.  Any ideas?

Comment: I think it is because you have 1-* relationship. This means that the MyEntity does not have the foreign key to the CustomClass since there may be many. However the CustomClass should have foreign key to the CustomClass. The foreign key on the CustomClass tells which MyEntity they "belong" to and you can have my CustomClass entities with the same foreign key value meaning they all "belong" to the same MyEntity entity.

Comment: It is a 1-* relationship.  So, I need to create a MyEntityID foreign key on the CustomClass, right?  Do I need to do any mapping (DbModelBuilder)?  I think I'm good after this.

Comment: If you want to be able to access the foreign key value then yes - you need a property (otherwise the column will be created in the database but you will not be able to access it in your app). Here is the link to tutorials http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907 where you can find more details on configuring relationships. If you don't need a foreign key you but you want to access the parent entity you can add a navigation property - a property that points to the parent type. You may also want to make both properties virtual to enable lazy loading.